# How to convert field labels to search boxes in views

Tags: views

I have a requirement where I need to convert the labels of specific/all fields of a view to search boxes on user click. The search box will be an autocomplete field.
Here, say for eg. the label TITLE gets converted to a search box on user click and provides suggestions(from the title field) as the user types characters

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since these are completely different things you may want to add the autocomplete fields as exposed filters from the view and then add them to the label using javascript. You could use jQuery .append into the label tag with a click listener.

Comment: that's a good suggestion Miquel, let me give it a try